# scrollview is slow when containing a long data in textview

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I am developing a rss feed news application and I used scrollview to show title and description.Description and title data I am getting from webpage that is too long, and I am adding that content to my textviews(title and desc) so that when I scroll it is extremly slow.
plz help

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, so people can show you where the issues might be.

Answer (score 6):

Use Viewholder class to hold UI controls

like

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView Title;

    TextView Description;

}
```

and for getView

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.Your_layout_file,
                            null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.Title= (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.titletextview);

            holder.Description= (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }

        else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

                    //your another code here
```

}

Using this your scroll will improve let me know if any doubt

Comment: You have not add your code for view otherwise i can give you batter answer